# Can't figure out why draft-js is not shown

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I followed [draft-js document](https://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/overview.html#content) to create a very simple demo of draft-js.

Everything seems work well, but when I open the url in Chrome, I can only see a white blank page (there is a hidden editor component there but is not visible)

There is no error on the console of the browser.

The demo project is here: https://github.com/js-demos/react-draft-js-demo, you can clone it and follow the readme to run it.

I have reviewed the code very carefully, but can't figure out why.

Comment: may not the problem, but a editor without content is WHITE BLANK. make a click to check if the cursor blinks.

Comment: it is happening the same to me, how did you solve it?

Comment: also same issue, anything????

Answer (score 23):

If you just use the sample code on the official website of Draft.js, you will see nothing on the page. It's just a blank text input field. If you click that field, you could type something. Draft.js is not a out of the box plugin, but a "a framework for building rich text editors in React".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Hope you figured it out, if not (or for anyone else), the solution for me was two step:

1. Download the [Draft.css](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/a26a2b3bebe916526e8def9c4cb8aef02262abb5/src/component/utils/DraftStyleDefault.css) file and include it in your source code.
2. Reference said file in your `index.html` as such:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/components/Draft.css" />`

In other words, your problem was to do with the styling of the Draft-js Editor, since for you the editor was 'hidden' i.e. without any discernible box around it etc.

Comment: You should actually just use the file bundled in the library. Just import into your project like this `import 'draft-js/dist/Draft.css';` ... still didn't fix the issue for me, but it did add all the CSS

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I tried a lot to solve this problem but in vain. What I did is using another package that is built on the top of draft js, and It's working fine.

you can find it here:https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no genius, but might I recommend this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGxdCXyMC7k

In short, it looks like the default is just a Rich Text Editor enabler type thing. You want more of a single instance, like their demo in the 'Rich Styling' section of the docs.